# FileProvider error "Failed to find configured root that contains /data/data/sawbodeployer.entm.illinois.edu ..."

Tags: android, provider, download-manager, android-fileprovider

I download video by android download manager and want to share this video, I follow through Manifas

```
 <provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="my.domain"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/paths" />
    </provider>
```

and in file path.xml add this:

```
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <files-path name="video_folder" path="files/"/>
</paths>
```

and use this provider:

```
File file = new File(getActivity().getFilesDir() , videoPath);
                Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getContext(), "my.domain", file);
                Intent intent = ShareCompat.IntentBuilder.from(getActivity())
                        .setType("video/3gp")
                        .setStream(uri)
                        .setChooserTitle("Choose bar")
                        .createChooserIntent()
                        .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
                startActivity(intent);
```

but I get error :

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to find configured root that contains /data/data/sawbodeployer.entm.illinois.edu/files/AKA1_Fante_Ghana_HandWashing_Final.3gp

Where is its problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace:

```
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <files-path name="video_folder" path="files/"/>
    <files-path name="name" path="path" />
</paths>
```

with:

```
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <files-path name="video_folder" />
</paths>
```

`path` is used when there is some specific subdirectory under the root that you want to serve from. Your file is directly in `getFilesDir()`, and so you cannot use `path`.

Comment: You can use path=".".

Comment: @greenapps: True, though it doesn't change the results.