# Sharing internal file gives: Failed to find configured root that contains /data/data/com.myapp/app_profiles/profile_1/games/game_1.xml

Tags: java, android, android-fileprovider

I want to share a file `/data/data/com.myapp/app_profiles/profile_1/games/game_1.xml` via `ACTION_SEND`.

I've added this to the Manifest:

```
<provider
    android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
    android:authorities="com.myapp.fileprovider"
    android:grantUriPermissions="true"
    android:exported="false">
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
        android:resource="@xml/filepaths" />
</provider>
```

and my `filepaths.xml` is

```
<paths>
    <files-path path="app_profiles/profile_1/games/" name="myGame" />
</paths>
```

the Code (in class XYActivity) is:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);    
builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
        ....
        File file = FileManager.getGameFile(gameID);
        Uri fileUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(XYActivity.this,
                                "com.myapp.fileprovider", file);
```

I get the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to find configured root that contains /data/data/com.myapp/app_profiles/profile_1/games/game_1.xml
    at android.support.v4.content.FileProvider$SimplePathStrategy.getUriForFile(FileProvider.java:739)
    ...
```

I have checked with the file explorer, this file does exist!

About the file object I know

```
file.getPath()         /data/user/0/com.myapp/app_profiles/profile_1/games/game_1.xml
file.getAbsolutePath() /data/user/0/com.myapp/app_profiles/profile_1/games/game_1.xml
file.getName()         game_1.xml
file.getParent()       /data/user/0/com.myapp/app_profiles/profile_1/games
```

For the `path` in filepaths.xml I've tried different, even wrong, values:

```
path="app_profiles/profile_1/gamXes/"  
path="app_profiles/profile_1/games/"  
path="app_profiles/profile_1/games"  
path="profile_1/games"  
path="games/"  
path="games"
path="."
path="../games/"
```

It doesn't change a thing. This would suggest that they're all wrong and I just have to use the right value, but I don't what that would be/why mine doesn't work.

There are several similar answers and they don't work for me

no subdirectories:  [FileProvider error "Failed to find configured root that contains /data/data/sawbodeployer.entm.illinois.edu ..."](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44247796/3014199)
external storage:   [File Provider: Failed to find configured root that contains](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48801636/3014199),                         [java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to find configured root that contains](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52035090/3014199), many more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/data/data/com.myapp/app_profiles/profile_1/games/game_1.xml` is not a standard location, and `FileProvider` does not support it. `<files-path>` is for `getFilesDir()`, which would map to `/data/data/com.myapp/files/`, and your file is not inside of there.

Either:

- Store the files in a better spot (e.g., a directory off of `getFilesDir()`), or
- Write your own `ContentProvider` that can serve files from your desired location